# pentaho process selected rows

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

**Objective**

I have an excel sheet that has 10 rows. Now, I want to select rows 5 and 6 only.

[image]

**What I tried**

I am getting the rows to set `limit` in the `Excel Input` -> `Container`, but using limit I am only getting rows smaller than input limit. So please anyone tell me how can I get the above condition.

**Updated**

specified start row = 5 in `Sheets Tab`
[image]

Without specified start row
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all in content section you can specify the filter and it is working perfectly fine, I have checked.
For achieving your output you can simply use filter rows step, specify the values you want to in values condition.

Comment: Yes , i understood that i already tried this but in my condition i want to filter out rows by row number

Comment: I think OP is trying something in SQL like **SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10**

Answer (score 1):

With the `Excel input` step, on the `Sheet tab` you can specify a range. Tell you want to start on row 5, col 1. Tell also on the `Content tab`, that you do not want a header, and a limit 2.

This should work. However, the answer is a bit academic, and I would suggest @Working Hard's answer. Read every thing, then use a `Filter step`.  In this step you can put more than conditions, like row=5 or row=6, or like row>=5 and row<=6. To do this, put the first condition, then click on the small green `+` on top right and put the second condition. Afterwards, you can click on the AND to change it in OR (among others).

Comment: thank you for your answer, the first one step `content tab` is satisfied my requirement but if I set 5 as a starting row and then press get fields from the header in `fields tab` it sets 5th row as a header. I have updated my question and attached both the screenshot with the start row or without the start row.

Comment: Process in two steps. First `Start row = 1`and `header=Yes`, press the `Get fields` button to read the field names. Second `Start row=5` and `header=No`, *do not* press the `Get fields` button so the field names remains the same.

Comment: did you try this to execute with `header = No` just because when I tried this with `header = No` and after completed all the steps to integrate with the database when I executed I got this error  **No input fields defined!**

Comment: Even if i have not set the start row and unselected header in `content tab` it gives me the same above error.

Comment: Mind the `header` checkbox.